# What is the correct call method for "api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/{blog-identifier}/post/delete"

Tags: php, api, tumblr

I have done this before, and for the life of me, I cannot seem to reproduce the code I've previously written.

I am trying to delete specific posts on my blog that are outdated, so that they can be automatically re-published with updates.

I can post fine, no problems there.

The code I am having trouble with is:

```
$client->post("http://api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/.".$blog_name.".tumblr.com/post/delete?id=".$post_id);
```

If I run the above code, I get a print out like so:

```
stdClass Object ( [meta] => stdClass Object ( [status] => 401 [msg] => Unauthorized ) [response] => Array ( ) )
```

I have tried to modify it a little by changing up the url, and this is what I have come up with, but still, it does not seem to be working for me.

Query:

```
$client->post("http://api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/.".$blog_name.".tumblr.com/post/delete/".$post_id);
```

Response:

```
stdClass Object ( [meta] => stdClass Object ( [status] => 404 [msg] => Not Found ) [response] => Array ( ) )
```

One of my errors is saying not found, and another error is saying I am not authorised, when I clearly am, being able to make posts, and also follow, unfollow users.

Any help would be great!

Comment: My calling method url is working fine here at https://apigee.com/console/tumblr so I am thinking it has something to do with how I am authorising my blog. But in saying that, I am authorising my blog the exact same way that I do for when I post to my blog.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just letting you all know that I solved the issue. It had nothing to do with the call method. The call method works completely fine in this format (for anyone else seeking):

`https://api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/`**`{$blogname}`**`/post/delete?id=`**`{$post_id}`**

**Note though**, it is required to **re-pass** a blogs authentication through to the tumblr server, if you are performing/calling an api request that is different to a previously performed/called api request.